# Content Organizer Rules overrides Folder level Permission

Tags: content

I have various folders under Document Library with Contribute rights to different group.

I use content organizer rules to route the document to appropriate folder by checking a metadata column (For ex  If Department = HR, the document should go to Documents\HR Folder

All the Contributor groups have Contribute permission in DropOff Library.

The issue is, If someone from (Ex) "IT" dept  enters meta data column values as "HR,   It still uploads the document to HR Folder eventhough the IT user doesn't have Contributer permission to HR Folder.

Could someone help me how to restrict this?

I thought the document should route to DropOff library either the  user tries to upload / Add a document to a folder where they dont have appropriate permission.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems the answer is NO

http://www.scottjamison.com/blog/2010/11/the-sharepoint-2010-content-organizer/

Comment: Please could you add the essential parts of the answer here, in addition the link? See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.